# With form validation: why onsubmit="return functionname()" instead of onsubmit="functionname()"?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The question is pretty self-explanatory. I don't understand what the return is doing in the following code:

```
<form onsubmit="return somefunction()">
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You need the return so the true/false gets passed up to the form's submit event (which looks for this and prevents submission if it gets a false).

Lets look at some standard JS:

```
function testReturn() { return false; }
```

If you just call that within any other code (be it an onclick handler or in JS elsewhere) it will get back false, but you need to do something with that value.

```
...
testReturn()
...
```

In that example the return value is coming back, but nothing is happening with it. You're basically saying execute this function, and I don't care what it returns. In contrast if you do this:

```
...
var wasSuccessful = testReturn();
...
```

then you've done something with the return value.

The same applies to onclick handlers. If you just call the function without the return in the onsubmit, then you're saying "execute this, but don't prevent the event if it return false." It's a way of saying execute this code when the form is submitted, but don't let it stop the event.

Once you add the return, you're saying that what you're calling should determine if the event (submit) should continue.

This logic applies to many of the onXXXX events in HTML (onclick, onsubmit, onfocus, etc).

Comment: I fixed a bug and then searched on the bug and found this. ;) good answer BTW.

Answer (score 17):

An extension to what GenericTypeTea says - Here is a concrete example:

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
```

The above form **will not submit**, whereas...

```
<form onsubmit="false">
```

...does nothing, i.e. the form **will submit**.

Without the `return`, `onsubmit` doesn't receive a value and the event is executed just like without any handler at all.

Answer (score 13):

Returning `false` from the function will stop the event continuing. I.e. it will stop the form submitting.

i.e.

```
function someFunction()
{
    if (allow) // For example, checking that a field isn't empty
    {
       return true; // Allow the form to submit
    }
    else
    {
       return false; // Stop the form submitting
    }
}
```

Comment: But why won't the function return false if we just had onSubmit="someFunction()"?

Comment: For example, function test() {return "asdf"}; alert(test()); triggers an alert that reads "asdf", but I didn't have to say alert(return test());

Comment: @zjmiller - Because `return` indicates that the value of the expression should be returned to the submit routine. If the expression evaluates to false, the submit routine is cancelled.

Comment: To amplify GenericTypeTea's excellent explanations, think of onsubmit as a Javascript variable and the stuff in the quotes as a Javascript function. So both "someFunction()" and "return somefunction()" will cause someFunction() to be executed, but "someFunction()" causes the return value from someFunction() to be discarded, whereas "return someFunction()" assigns the return value to the onsubmit variable. This is all due to the loosey-goosey nature of Javacript, where you're allowed to define functions any way you want, so the interpreter has to accept whatever you do...

Answer (score 9):

When onsubmit (or any other event) is supplied as an **HTML attribute**, the string value of the attribute (e.g. `"return validate();"`) is injected as the **body** of the actual **onsubmit handler function** when the DOM object is created for the element.

Here's a brief proof in the browser console:

```
var p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = '<form onsubmit="return validate(); // my statement"></form>';
var form = p.childNodes[0];

console.log(typeof form.onsubmit);
// => function

console.log(form.onsubmit.toString());
// => function onsubmit(event) {
//      return validate(); // my statement
//    }
```

So in case the **`return`** keyword is supplied in the injected statement; when the submit handler is triggered the return value received from `validate` function call will be passed over as the return value of the submit handler and thus take effect on controlling the submit behavior of the form.

Without the supplied `return` in the string, the generated `onsubmit` handler would not have an explicit return statement and when triggered it would return **`undefined`** (the default function return value) irrespective of whether `validate()` returns `true` or `false` and the form would be submitted in both cases.

Comment: Yes.. that is what I want to read; `onsubmit` is actually a function body, works like `{...}` of a function, not an attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful description (and evidence!) of what is actually happening behind the scenes - this really answers the question with a explanation that aids understanding.

Answer (score 5):

HTML event handler code behaves like the body of a JavaScript function.  Many languages such as C or Perl implicitly return the value of the last expression evaluated in the function body.  JavaScript doesn't, it discards it and returns undefined unless you write an explicit `return`*EXPR*.

Comment: That is a valid answer... The first sentence explains it all.

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
function check(){
    return false;
}
 </script>

<form name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return check();" action="target">
<input type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="enviar" />

</form>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? In addition, the question is two years old. Please try putting your effort in unanswered questions instead.