# How to get form onsubmit to check terms for Google Checkout button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-checkout, html-input

I'm using Google Checkout and having a problem with the onsubmit function.

I have an "Agree to terms" checkbox that I've put in place so that users must accept the terms before continuing with the checkout.  I'm calling a function on the HTML form element...

```
function preCheckout() {
        if( !document.getElementById('terms').checked ) {
            // Requirements not accepted.
            $('.warning').animate({top: -$('.warning').outerHeight()}, 500);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

which contains the google checkout button like so:

```
<form method="POST"
        action="https://sandbox.google.com..."
            accept-charset="utf-8" onsubmit="preCheckout();">

        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="accept_terms" value="" />
            <p>I agree to all the terms and requirements...</p>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Simple Notes Monthly Subscription"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="item_description_1" value=""/>
        <input type="hidden" name="item_quantity_1" value="1"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="item_price_1" value=""/>
        <input type="hidden" name="item_currency_1" value="USD"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="shopping-cart.merchant-private-data" value="" />

        <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="0.065"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="tax_us_state" value="UT"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="_charset_"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="continue-shopping-url" value="/thankyou.php" />

        <input type="image" name="Google Checkout" id="google-btn" alt="Fast checkout through Google"
        src="https://checkout.google.com/buttons/checkout.gif?merchant_id=id&w=180&h=46&style=trans&variant=text&loc=en_US"
        height="46" width="180"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

However the page continues on with or without the checkbox being checked.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI [Here's the question I really meant to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195933/with-form-validation-why-onsubmit-return-functionname-instead-of-onsubmit)

When you right into the `onsubmit` line it's self, you return the `true` or `false` respectively, right? Like so:

`onsubmit="return false;"`

Well let's breakdown what is actually going in your code. Because you are potentially returning `false` in your code, here's the two possibilities of what might happen on submit.

```
onsubmit="false" // form is a success and performs form action
onsubmit="" // form is a success and performs form action
```

but what you're really looking for is `onsubmit="return false;"` or `onsubmit="return true;"` so here's what you need to do:

```
function preCheckout() {
    if( !document.getElementById('terms').checked ) {
        // Requirements not accepted.
        $('.warning').animate({top: -$('.warning').outerHeight()}, 500);
        return false;
    }

    // return true if everything is fine
    return true;
}
```

However, the **most important** part is this:

```
<!-- all I did was add a "return" to your onsubmit -->
<form method="POST" action="https://sandbox.google.com..." accept-charset="utf-8" onsubmit="return preCheckout();">
```