# Form doesn't call JS func on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My forgot pass form doesn't call my javascript ajax on submit, here's my code

```
<form onsubmit="SendMail(this.email.value);">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
                <input type="submit" id="black_button" value="Request Password Renewal Code">
            </form>
```

And here's my JS script

```
<script>
        function SendMail(email)
        {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    if(response=='redirect')
                    {
                        document.location.href="forgotpassword.php?success=1"; //If the response is redirect then redirect the user to another page
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#FPErrorMSG").html(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        $("#FPErrorMSG").css("display","block"); // If not then show the error message
                    }
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","system/forgotpassword/sendmail.php?email=" + email,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
```

It doesn't call the Javascript function, example when I enter my email as abc@d.com, it will only change my url to forgotpassword.php?email=abc@d.com. When I change my input field name from email to mail, it changes my url to forgotpassword.php?mail=abc@d.com

Comment: Since you are not returning false from your `onsubmit` handler, it won't prevent the browser to submit the form. Try adding `return false;` after your function call.

Comment: Have you tried returning false to prevent the form from doing its own submit behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return `false` in your javascript function. Otherwise the form will be submitted the normal way after the javascript function has been called.

```
<form onsubmit="return SendMail(this.email.value);">

function SendMail(email) {
   ...
   return false;
}
```

or

```
<form onsubmit="SendMail(this.email.value); return false;">
```

You should have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195933/with-form-validation-why-onsubmit-return-functionname-instead-of-onsubmit) question.